# What is Gdx.graphics.getWitdth() measured in?

Tags: android, graphics, libgdx, textures, scale

I'm using getWidth and getHeight a lot for scaling textures in my Libgdx project.  What units are these in (pixels?)
Also, if I want the texture to look consistent on different phones, should I use getWidth/Height to scale, or some number value like width = 100, height = 50?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [getWidth](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Graphics.html#getWidth--) and [getHeight](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Graphics.html#getHeight--) are both measured in pixels. Although you can use these for your dimensions, usually what you'll want to do to get a consistent look across phones is to use a camera of some sort (for 2d games, generally an [OrthographicCamera](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Orthographic-camera)).

What you'll probably want to do is give the camera some fixed width and height, and then do all of your drawing through the camera's transformations. Something like:

```
SpriteBatch batch = new SpriteBatch();
OrthographicCamera camera = new OrthographicCamera(800, 600);
//some code here
batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
batch.begin();
//draw your textures here
batch.end();
```

This should keep the scale of your images consistent across phones. Keep in mind that if there is too much of a stretch/compress, your textures may look distorted.

Comment: will the camera automatically stretch to fit the entire phone screen?

Comment: @henzdaddy yes, the camera just changes the coordinate system. The viewport of the camera should fill the screen

Answer (score 0):

@clearlyspam23 that's exactly what I'm looking for, thank you!  Just a note, set it up like:

```
OrthographicCamera camera = new OrthographicCamera();
camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 600);
```

The other way looks like it positioned the camera origin at 800, 600.

Thanks again!